# How can I convert a range to a table with PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I use the convert range-to-table function in Excel for several reasons; easy styling, easier formulas, in-table sort & filtering, total row functions etc.

Is it possible to convert a range to a table, like the MS Excel 2010/2013 function, and if then, how?

I have search the documentation and SO, but am unable to find relevant information.

Comment: Do you mean pivot table?

Comment: No, I mean a standard Excel table, see here how to do it in Excel: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca

Comment: That functionality doesn't exist in PHPExcel

Comment: Aight, thank you, @MarkBaker.

Comment: it's been over a year since this post was created. unfortunately no news about this important feature. excel tables can expand and apply the same formulas etc to the next rows on insertion. I need to find a way for that too